# Good way to create a double-lined border?

Tags: css

This is what I'm talking about (with two different colors):

[image]

My only solution was to create two span divs and add a border-right on one and a border-left on the other. However, I feel that there is a way to achieve this in less code.

HTML

```
<span class="border-right"></span>
<span class="border-left"></span>
```

CSS

```
.border-right { border-right: 1px solid #eee }
.border-left { border-left: 1px solid #888 }
```

Does anybody know of a better way to achieve this? Also, the height of the black background div doesn't have a set height so how would I make sure that the two `span` elements fit from top to bottom no matter the height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to give a separate left/right border with the span width as zero.

```css
span { 
  display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 24px; height: 24px; 
}
span.dbl {
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  width: 0px;
}
div { background-color: #eee; }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Something on left</span>
  <span class="dbl"></span>
  <span>Something on right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain? Is this answer wrong? Is this not useful?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `pseudo` element

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first,
.second {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.first {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.first:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  right: -4px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">test</div>
<div class="second">test</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer :) , seems a bit too long

Comment: its long because it should be at the center of the two div like your answer @Mohit.Bhasi but box-shadow is not supported in [ie8](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
border-right:2px double black;
```

Comment: I need the two borders to be different colors.

Comment: @J82 I think I got it. Check my answer out

Answer (score 0):

@Akshay and @abhitalks got nice answers, the easiest way out is by doing so:

```
border-right: 10px solid blue;
box-shadow: 10px 0 0 red;
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/off3f1gg/

Comment: yes. a good trick. add a snippet to your answer so that it is easily demonstrable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you try this code it help

```
    <h2>Demo 1</h2>
<div class="header">
    <div class="left-shide"></div>
    <div class="right-shide"></div>    
</div>

<h2>Demo 2</h2>
<div class="header">
    <div class="left-shide2"></div>
    <div class="right-shide2"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgb(15, 15, 15);
    float:left;
}

.left-shide{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:20%;
    border-right:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
.right-shide{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:20%;
    border-left:1px solid rgb(60,60,60);
}



/*Demo 2 **/
.left-shide2{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:20%;
    box-shadow:1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.right-shide2{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:20%;
    border-left:1px solid rgb(60,60,60);
}
```

Live **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/2gmaukfs/)**